# Melt a complex mesh and then animate it using force fields

Tags: animation, mesh, force-fields

I am struggling while trying to perform a sequence which includes the following actions:

1. **Melt a mesh with a viscocity** like mercury or something similar.
2. **Animate it with a force field, to achieve a fusion effect**.

If you want I can send the blend file. I am a little bit frustated because I can`t achieve this effect.

Any help?

Comment: Use the Fluid Simulation.

Answer (score 2):

For the melting you have lots of options, for example:

- A high quality fluid simulation with a high viscosity.
- Shape keys + sculpting
- Cast modifier (Apply as shape key)

The fluid simulation is probably the best for a good melting animation and being able to control it with force fields, but fluid simulations require tons of processing power to look good in my experience. I would probably go with casting it to a sphere with a < 1 factor and a control object located slightly below the object. I'd apply that as a shape key and sculpt it a bit, and then only do the fluid sim when the object is already melted (there's less detail to lose when it's already smooth, and you might get away with lower settings.)